# How to use Vue.js file (not CDN) with Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I have almost completed my Admin Panel in laravel 5.7, however needed to use VueJS for some component. I am aware Vue comes by default with laravel, and also saw the app.js file under resources/js directory in laravel.

However, is there a possibility where I can use Vue.js file that I have downloaded, and import it with the script tag? I tried by placing the script and vue code in the blade file itself, but it conflicts with the laravel {{ blade_syntax }}.

Is there a systematic way to not use VueCLI, or CDN, but the plain vuejs file? Need I copy the vuejs file i downloaded inside Laravel Project? If so, where should I place the file?

Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the vue.js or any js,css script to the public folder of your laravel projects.
in your laravel projects look for public 
place your vue.js file anywhere in this folder say you put it to js folder
now to inculde it you use *asset ('js/vue.js')* on your blade.php file.
thats it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it didn't work. I have vue.js in public/js. I imported the script with src="js/vue.js" in my *.blade.php file. I have a div with id="answerbox". then below the div, I have another script tag where my vue code resides (a simple vue code with el: "answerbox", and data: "message"). 
The problem is when i try to display {{ message }}, the laravel blade syntax is conflicting as it uses the same syntax. Instead of message from the script just below the code, {{ message }} is expecting value on page load from server.

Comment: for laravel you can use `@{{$somevar}}` so that won't conflict with **vue** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)